# How to get values from Repeater control

Tags: asp.net

I am using repeater control to display online question paper to user. I am showing 50 questions to user. And i am giving 4 check boxes for every question to select answer. Now my doubt is how to get all 50 options that checked by user, and to compare those answers with correct answer tag in my XML. I am using XML file, not database.

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: What have you tried?  You should post some code showing what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate `Repeater` control, like...

```
if (Repeater1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < Repeater1.Items.Count; count++)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)Repeater1.Items[count].FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (chk.Checked)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get access to `Repeater` items you should use:

```
repeaterId.Items
```

To get access to all checked controls of a repeater (which are definitely `RadioButton` controls, as you should have one option per question), you can use:

```
foreach (ListViewDataItem item in repeaterId.Items)
{
    // Finding RadioButton controls by Id
    RadioButton firstOption = ((RadioButton)item.FindControl("firstOption"));
    RadioButton secondOption = ((RadioButton)item.FindControl("secondOption"));
    RadioButton thirdOption = ((RadioButton)item.FindControl("thirdOption"));
    RadioButton fourthOption = ((RadioButton)item.FindControl("fourthOption"));
    // Here you have four RadioButtones and you should only see which one of them is clicked. Then compare its value to correct value in your XML file.
}
```

Comment: ListViewDataItem does only exist from .NET 3.5 upwards. The correct type for an Item in repeater.Items would be RepeaterItem.

Comment: Also it could be better to not explicitely cast the control as RadioButton, and use the following instead: item.FindControl("FirstOption") as RadioButton;